# Глагол порочить

Tags: этимология

Неожиданно открыл для себя отсутствие в старославянском глагола "порочить", когда он появился в русском языке, какова его история?

Comment: тот кто не знает ответа жмёт минус?

Answer (score 3):

А почему Вы в старославянском  языке ищете глагол с полногласием -оро-? Его там и быть не может, но там был глагол **порицать**.

О его происхождении пишет Н.М.Шанский:

> Порица́ть. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Преф. производное от утраченного
>   рицати (ср. др.-рус. рикати «бранить»), итератива к решти «говорить»
>   (< *rekti). См. отречься, изречь; ц из к по третьей палатализации.
>   https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

От глагола поректи (порицать) при чередовании е//о образовано сущ. порокъ сначала в значении "порицание, упрёк", затем "то, что заслуживает порицания" - недостаток. А уж потом глагол порочить - порицать недостатки.

Comment: полногласием называется -оро-, стоящие в корне, в данном же случае начальное "о" относится к приставке